# When inside my VENV, PIP FREEZE shows I have a package installed but when I run my code, it says module not found

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, python-venv

After creating a venv, activating it and installing a few packages (Numpy), when I run my code which has "import numpy as np", it throws an error saying module not found. I did a PIP FREEZE in the cmd while still in the environment and it shows me the version of Numpy that is installed.

I am very confused why this is the case, I have deleted and recreated the environment multiple times to no avail.

Doing `pip list` and `pip freeze` shows this

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
numpy      1.23.0
```

Running my program which has the line `import numpy as np`
results in this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\TouristRoutingProblem\TouristRoutingProblem\00 classes\TouristRoutingProblem.py", line 2, in <module>    
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Curiously, when I run the following in the CMD this happens.

```
(my_env) PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\TouristRoutingProblem\touristroutingproblem\my_env> python
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(np)
```

The output is as follows, which suggests that numpy IS installed.

```
<module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\TouristRoutingProblem\\touristroutingproblem\\my_env\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>
```

Comment: Have you checked using `pip3 list` from venv and `numpy` package was exists in pip list?

Comment: PIP3 LIST does give me numpy inside! I have edited an included an image in the original post, hopefully it helps!

Comment: Please refrain from using unnecessary capital letters. It tends to be interpreted as shouting, which is generally frowned upon. If you need to accentuate some word(s), use `*` on each side of the word. If you want to  use code, like pip freeze, use backticks, ``, around the words: `pip freeze`. Please familiarize yourself with the editor when writing a question.

Comment: Let me guess: you don't use the normal Python interpreter in your virtual environment, but a full path to another Python interpreter. Use plain `python` inside a virtual environment.

Comment: I have recreated the venv using `python -m venv my_env` and the issue still persists. After using `pip list` and `pip freeze`, I can verify that numpy is indeed shown in both commands. This is after activate the venv and seeing (my_env) in the CMD. Apologies for the formatting, this is my first question on StackOverflow. 
I am a little unsure what steps to take from now, I have uninstalled and reinstalled Python a few times and recreated the venv as well. Any leads or direction will be much appreciated!

Comment: I have edited the question! Hope it conveys the appropriate information.

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: As of now, I click on the top right button in VSCode that says "Run Python File".

Comment: I have added onto the main post, apparently it seems to work if I run it in CMD?

Comment: Change your VSCode settings to use the correct interpreter for this code/virtual environment.

Comment: I had to do a `where.exe python` to get the correct file path and add that as a new path. Apologies, I did try changing interpreters earlier but i changed it among the options listed and neither worked. Thank you for helping so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> command to open the Command Palette, search for and select **Python:Select Interpreter**(Or click directly on the *python version* displayed in the lower right corner), and select the correct interpreter.

[image]

Comment: This solution worked! When I did this initially, there were two Pythons path shown and neither worked. I had to activate my virtual environment and do a `where.exe python` to get the file path before copying that file path and adding it as a new one.  Thank you for all the help.